# Retrieve CPT Posts from a specific category | WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I am currently retrieving posts from a custom post type using the following array:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'location',
        'value' => get_the_ID(),
        'compare' => 'like',
        )
    )
);
$events_list = new WP_Query($args);
```

It works great.

Now, I was wondering if I could retrieve these same posts but ONLY if they appear in the category ID '6'.

Can someone explain how I update my current code to allow this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'cat' instead of 'category':

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'cat' => 6,
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => 'location',
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => 'like',
         )
     )
);
$events_list = new WP_Query($args);
```